# What exactly is isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying linear algebra, and i know well what isomorphism is. But i have a problem to understand this concept.

Here is an example for explaining my problem explicitly.

> > If $S$ is any subset of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, then $(S^0)^0$ is the subspace spanned by S.

The proof in the text is as following.

Let $W$ be the subspace spanned by $S$. Clearly $W^0=S^0$. Then

$$\dim W+\dim W^0 = \dim V$$
$$\dim W^0 + \dim W^{00} = \dim V^*$$

Since $\dim V = \dim V^*$ we have $\dim W = \dim W^{00}$

$\textbf{Since $W$ is a subspace of $W^{00}$}$, we see that $W=W^{00}$

I don't understand the bold sentence. What we know is that $W$ is isomorphic to $W^{00}$, but it does not mean that $W$ is actually a subspace of $W^{00}$. Explain me about this.

Comment: I don't understand this notation. What does $W^0$ mean?

Comment: From context, I gather that $S^0$ means the orthogonal complement of $S$ (as a subset of the dual $V^*$).  The usual notation for this is $S^\perp$.

Comment: It means annihilator of $W$. Sorry for having not mentioned.

Comment: Are you working from Halmos' book by any chance?

Comment: I didn't study set theory...

Comment: There is a book "Finite dimensional vector spaces" by Halmos I assume @snulty meantthat one. not Naive Set Theory.

Comment: @quid Yes that was the one I meant! I think it's the only time I think I've come across annihilators in a linear algebra book. However as it turns out, just checking there, it's also in the book by Steve Roman I'm working through part of at the moment. Nevermind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What we know is that $W$ is isomorphic to $W^{00}$, but it does not mean that $W$ is actually a subspace of $W^{00}$.

You are correct that from the equality of the dimensions it only follows that the spaces are isomorphic.

The fact that $W$ is contained in $W^{00}$ is a fact to be observed independently of the directly preceding arguments. It could also be asserted right at the start of the entire argument.

If you have difficulty seeing this inclusions recall that:

- $W^o =\{f \in V^{\ast} \colon f(w) = 0 , \, \forall w\in W \}$,
- $W^{oo} = \{w \in V \colon f(w) = 0 , \, \forall f\in W^{o} \}$. 
  From this it is direct that every $w \in W$ is in  $W^{oo}$ as the $f \in W^{o}$ are *defined*  to vanish on $w \in W$.

(The above assumes that one identifies $V$ with $V^{\ast \ \ast}$; but if one does not then $W$ does not equal $W^{oo}$ so this must be done in this context.)

Comment: In my text, there is 2 preceding theorems, but i can't draw the fact that $W$ is contained in $W^{00}$ from them. The first is $V$ is isomorphic to $V^{**}$(the double dual) and the second is each basis for $V^*$ is the dual of some basis for $V$.

Comment: I expanded the post.

Comment: In my text, $V^{**}$ is defined like this way. For each vector $\alpha$ in $V$ define $L_{\alpha}(f) = f(\alpha)$, and $f$ in $V^*$, then the set of $L_{\alpha}$ is $V^{**}$. However in your answer you defined $W^{00}$ as the subset of $V$. Is it putting the cart before the horse?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. But then the discussion should continue to *identify* $\alpha$ with $L_{\alpha}$ and $V$ with $V^{\ast \ast}$. This is what I said in the parenthetical remark.  If this is *not* done it is just *not* true that $W = W^{oo}$. It cannot be true as $W^{oo}$ is in $V^{\ast \ast}$ while $W$ is in $V$.

Comment: Oh i see. You mean that theoretically we cannot draw the fact that $W$ is subspace of $W^{00}$, but the prerequisite is that author assumes $V$ is actually $V^{**}$. So we can have the fact $W$ is subspace of $W^{00}$. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. More concretely there is a canonical isomorphism $i: V \to V^{\ast \ast}$ and $i (W)= W^{oo}$. However, often as the isomorphism is canonical one in fact identifies $V$ with $V^{\ast \ast}$. Then $i(W)$ becomes $W$ and we have the equality.

Comment: You've offered any help I could possibly have given with your answer and comments! +1

Comment: i see. thank you @quid